# How to login on azure virtual machine using domain Admin credentials, In domain added machine

Tags: windows, azure, azure-diagnostics, azure-connect

I have created two virtual machine on azure. in one machine I have configured Active Directory/Domain Controller and added other machine in configured domain.

The question is how to login on second machine using Domain Administrator controller.

thanks
ravi

Answer (score 0):

By simply indicating the domain you are logging with:

> Username: DOMAINNAME\Administrator
>
> Password: Your Admin Password

As simple as that.

Comment: It will work, if the machine your are loggin-in is joined to the domain where your provided U/P exists. I've done it for at least 3 different deployment solutions and it works when you have all setup as required. BTW you can't have AD out of the box in Cloud Only. There are tricks and workaround you have to do, for this to work. But if you really joined a VM machine to an AD in VM in Azure, you will have no issues.